# Is it possible to create an installer for an application built using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am building a web application using Codeigniter, which will be running on localhost. Is there any way to create an installer for it so that any user can install it (including XAMPP server) like regular software on windows?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you want PHP to install a PHP server?

Comment: Sorry probably I didn't explain it correctly. I don't want PHP to install anything... I have created a web application using Codeigniter and now when any user want to install it I want them to install it like regular software on windows.  So I want to create an installer for the application. I just want to know if it is possible and if then how? Thanks :)

Comment: @Srijon -- You should look into [PHAR](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php), as I believe that is the sort of support you're looking for. You could create an installer a 'la InstallShield or something, but creating a web installer is more fitting to the nature of the application and the environment under which it would be "installed".

Comment: It still doesn't make much sense - or maybe you have to explain some more. It sounds like you wan't something like a `setup.exe` that opens a Windows installer - and then what? Should it upload your app to a FTP server? Or install it locally? Should it configure a database? Configure anything at all? What about Mac/Linux users? It somewhat unclear what you really wan't.

Comment: Thanks Repox for your reply. You are right I want to have something like setup.exe and when it opens the windows installer I just want it to install XAMPP server to a drive(lets say C drive) and then create a folder called "my application" and inside the folder put my php files and then create a database. It wont have to upload anything or do anything other than what I just mentioned.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this [GoInstaller](https://github.com/abedputra/GoInstaller)

What is GoInstaller? GoInstaller is installer for CodeIgniter with user interface (UI).

How to use?

- Download
- Place the install folder inside/root the codeigniter folder
- Open SQL command file on assets->sqlcommand.sql
- Add command SQL into install.sql
- Make sure your codeigniter database (application->config->database.php) to cmod 777
- Open http://(Your Link)/install
- Fill the form ,Hostname, Username, etc
- Your URL website is link to redirect to your website after the installer is done
- Done

Comment: I love it a lot.

Comment: Nice but I think script should also update `$config['base_url']` in `application->config->config.php`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off using something like [Phar](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php) to compress and distribute your application. You could roll your own, taking advantage of `__HALT_COMPILER`, etc., however Phar should support most anything you need.

Creating a binary installer for a PHP application (*the prototypical `setup.exe`*) is not likely to be a good decision, as most people using shared hosting providers are not going be able to execute and install the application to the server.

A web installer is not only more portable, but typically what's expected for web application installation procedures. Also, writing the installer in PHP allows you to use your existing codebase during the installation procedure to perform diagnostics, compatibility checks, and essentially anything you need.

Comment: Hi, Bracketworks I am planning to run my application only on localhost so I don't have to worry about the fact that shared hosting providers are not going be able to execute and install the application to the server. .. :) And Since I am not very expert at PHP I have no idea about Phar.. I think I have to google it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create the CI app with empty values in the database config file then use CI to do a find/replace on the contents of the file based on the inputs from a form e.g. mysql host, username, password.

Step 1:  Create a form, validate entries, then check the db values are correct before committing them to  the file (use something like:

```
$config['hostname'] = $this->input->post('hostname');
$config['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
$config['password'] = $this->input->post('password');
$config['database'] = $this->input->post('database');

$this->load->database($config);
```

If that all works correctly then do your find/replace on the database entries in the database.php file in config.

You couldn't put database in the autoload.php file though using this method (unless you replace that too after setup has run successfully).

In CI version 2 onwards everything else pretty much sorts itself out eg paths etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-cross-platform-application-development/) in the past for something like that. Works great!